# Display items in listbox with entity framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, webmethod, service-reference

I am trying to display items from my Entity framework database into listbox. I have two different projects. First is Empty Web app and the second is Windows Forms (client).

When i go into menu in my WF app, i need users to display and refresh automatically.

This is my code:

**User class**

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Club { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
}
```

**WEB SERVICE**

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<Users> displayUsers()
    {
       using (var db = new Database())
       {
           return db.userList.ToList();
       }
    }
```

**WINDOWS FORMS CODE**

```
private void osveziPodakte()
    {
        ServiceReference1.mojWebServiceSoapClient client = new    ServiceReference1.mojWebServiceSoapClient();
        listBox1.Items.Add(client.displayUsers());
    }
```

When i run the program, users that are in database do not get displayed inti listbox. Can you guys please help me fix the code?

Thank you very much!

I also get this exception when i run the program.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   Server was unable to process request. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document.

Comment: Do you get an exception, is the list blank or something else entirely? Bear in mind that you're adding a list of objects to the listbox. Unless you override the `ToString` method of your user class, it won't know which fields to display

Comment: @Basic yes i get exception... check updated version. And yes the list is blank whatever i try ,eventhough there is data in database

Comment: Ok, then let's remove the things that aren't causing problems (yet). We can ignore the Listbox and probably the whole client (winforms). You haven't mentioned how you're hosting the service. I assume it's WCF due to the `WebMethod` attribute? Is this being done in a 2nd project or is one project both hosting and consuming the service? Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt (under VS/Tools in start menu) and type `wcftestclient` then press enter. You should get a test UI that will allow you to connect to WCF and test the methods there. I'm guessing the problem is with the service not the client.

Comment: @Basic It's ASP.NET Empty Web Application. Web App is the host and Windows Forms is a client where im dispaying data, adding users, etc...I dont really have "command prompt" under tools. Program works fine so far, i can add users. I could also display them with Console application yesterday...now im trying with Windows Forms and it doesnt work. It must be error in code (objects, strings)

Comment: Ok, the reason I think the problem with the service and not the client is that the exception says "There was an error generating the XML document". The XML is generated by the service and consumed by the client. Just to prove me wrong, can you try the client tool? The link on my machine is called `Open VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` or `VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` for 2012/2013 respectively. Failing that, can you still call `displayUsers` from the console app? If you're sure the service is good, break the client into 2 steps...

Comment: `var users = client.displayUsers();`, then `listBox1.Items.AddRange(users.Select(x => x.Name));`. Put a breakpoint on the 2nd line and make sure that `users` is being populated correctly. Note the use of `AddRange` as it's multiple items, not `Add` which takes a single item

Comment: it doesnt work. its still giving the same error:(